# Is Mincha an עת רצון?

Tags: tefilla, mincha-afternoon-prayer

Someone told me that mincha is an עת רצון because מידת הרחמים is strongest at that point.

Is there a source for this?

Comment: answered in this question? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26878/eliyahu-was-answered-as-soon-as-he-prayed-how-does-that-prove-the-importance-of

Comment: I heard the opposite. I heard that minha is a time of very strict din, but it's only an et rason on shabbat, hence the addition of the pauk vaani tefilati...

Comment: @147zcbm I've seen your claim, also. However, IIRC, I think every day mincha is also an *et ratzon* since Eliyahu was answered during Mincha. Although not stated, I assume he did his "shtick" on a weekday as he and the group favoring ba'al carried buckets of water and lit fire.

Comment: Although the aforementioned Zohar states that the attribute of harsh Heavenly judgment takes control at the time of Mincha (besides for Shabbat when, on the contrary, the time of Mincha is a time of great Heavenly mercy). http://halachayomit.co.il/EnglishPrint.asp?HalachaID=3151

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Shitta Mekubetset to Bava Kamma (82a)](http://www.sefaria.org/Shita_Mekubetzet_on_Bava_Kamma.82a?lang=bi) (middle of the first paragraph) cites a Gaon that it is an "et ratson". This is found in Otsar HaGeonim Megillah (23b) in the name of [R. Sar Shalom Gaon](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/sar-shalom-ben-boaz).  [Tosafot to Pesahim (107a)](http://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Pesachim.107b.1?lang=bi) writes the same. Numerous contemporaneous and later sources writes this as well.

Comment: Thanks again and thank you for putting in your time and effort to find this answer for me.

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah you are very welcome. you can reciprocate by making users' jobs easier by including sources for your questions, and by voting and marking correct their answers to your questions. E.g. [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/64556/8775), [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/62129/8775), and [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/61848/8775), if you like them.