# Zohar in hebrew online

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, internet, zohar

I was looking online to see if the Zohar was available in Hebrew.

Does anyone know where I can find it?

Comment: You want a Hebrew translation from the Aramaic?

Comment: http://www.ateret4u.com/online/d_root__106_kblh.html

Comment: @Seth J: Yes please.

Comment: I am not sure why this question deserves -3 when this question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9197/does-the-torah-discuss-aliens about the halachic status of aliens will presumably be useful to much fewer readers yet received +35.

Answer (score 5):

[HebrewBooks](http://hebrewbooks.org/) has the volumes of R. Ashlag's edition , which includes translation of the Aramaic into Hebrew. Type "הסולם" into the site's 'Title' search box to get the list of volumes.

Answer (score 2):

You can find it in the original and with a Hebrew translation at [Torat Emet](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/d_root__106_kabala.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the Zohar online with translations in this webpage.
https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar.1.1a?lang=bi

You can also find a lot of jewish texts translated to english.

Answer (score 1):

[Complete Zohar, Tikkunim, and Zohar Chadash in Aramaic with Hebrew translation, in 10 volumes of PDF, divided for yearly or 3-year learning](http://ha-zohar.net/ZOHAR_LHK_MACHULAK.htm)

http://ha-zohar.net/ZOHAR_LHK_MACHULAK.htm